# Can't retrieve instance by using interface

Tags: c#, interface

Goal:
Retrieve all instance of List<> from interface GameFactory

Problem:
I retrieve error message "Interfaces cannot contain fields".

How should I do in orde to retrieve all instance from interface GameFactory. Any good idea?

// Fullmetalboy

```
public interface GameFactory<T>
{



}

public class NiceGameFactory : GameFactory<Player>
{

    public List<Obstacle> _my_G_Obstacle;
    public List<Action> _my_G_Action = new List<Action>();
    public Player _myPlayer;
    public void RetrieveObstacle()
    {



    }

    public NiceGameFactory()
    {

        _my_G_Obstacle = new List<Obstacle>();
        _my_G_Obstacle.Add(new Wizard());
        _my_G_Obstacle.Add(new Wall());
        _my_G_Obstacle.Add(new Elephant());
        _my_G_Obstacle.Add(new DPexam());

        _my_G_Action.Add(new BowAndShakeHandsAction());
        _my_G_Action.Add(new RunAndHideAction());
        _my_G_Action.Add(new BargainAndBuyAction());
        _my_G_Action.Add(new ChainsawAction());
        _my_G_Action.Add(new ClimbAction());
        _my_G_Action.Add(new CastAspellAction());
        _my_G_Action.Add(new SurrenderAction());

        _myPlayer = new OrdinaryPlayer();
    }


}

public class NastyGameFactory
{

    public List<Obstacle> _my_G_Obstacle;
    public List<Action> _my_G_Action;
    public Player _myPlayer;


    public NastyGameFactory()
    {
        _my_G_Obstacle.Add(new Dragon());
        _my_G_Obstacle.Add(new Bomb());
        _my_G_Obstacle.Add(new Samuray());
        _my_G_Obstacle.Add(new SumoWrestler());
        _my_G_Obstacle.Add(new Gangster());

        _my_G_Action.Add(new BowAndShakeHandsAction());
        _my_G_Action.Add(new RunAndHideAction());
        _my_G_Action.Add(new SwordAction());
        _my_G_Action.Add(new RifleAction());
        _my_G_Action.Add(new OfferFoodAction());
        _my_G_Action.Add(new ChainsawAction());
        _my_G_Action.Add(new CastAspellAction());
        _my_G_Action.Add(new BargainAndBuyAction());
        _my_G_Action.Add(new SurrenderAction());

        _myPlayer = new HeroPlayer();
    }


}
```

Comment: While your at it, take a look at the microsoft naming guidelines [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx), future developers will thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the lists as accessible via properties on the interface.

```
public interface GameFactory <T>
{

  public List<Obstacle> _my_G_Obstacle { get; set; }
  public List<Action> _my_G_Action { get; set; }

}
```

(This is a better practice anyway than having public fields.)